# How to let UIScrollView invoke scrollViewDidScroll, when contentSize is decreased

Tags: ios, scrollview

I have a dynamic UITableView, which will insert and delete rows when clicking button.

```
-(IBAction)foldingClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.isInfoFolded = !self.isInfoFolded;
    if( self.isInfoFolded)
    {
       //self.mainTable remove rows

    }else
    {
       //self.mainTable insert rows
    }    
}
```

and I did some animation in `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    CGFloat main_offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;    
    //animation    
    CGRect image_frame = self.imageView.frame;
    if((main_offset >= 0 ) && (main_offset <= self.imageView.frame.size.height))
    {
        image_frame.origin.y = main_offset/2;
    }else
    {
        image_frame.origin.y = image_frame.size.height/2;
    }
}
```

It mostly works fine. But when I

1. click button to insert rows. ( the tableView contentSize increase )
2. Scroll table view to a big offset.
3. click button to delete rows. ( the tableView contentSize decrease )

Result: The table view will scroll up because the decreased `contentSize` is making the valid `contentOffset` smaller too, during which process my `scrollViewDidScroll` method is not invoked, that makes the animation incomplete, and leaving `imageView` at wrong position in my case.

I tried calling `scrollViewDidScroll:` right after removing rows. However `scrollViewDidScroll:` is invoked only once and the contentOffset is '0' in that execute.  It's not gradually down to '0' .   So is there any way for making `scrollViewDidScroll` being called continuously like it usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UITableView`'s message

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

When you're inserting or deleting rows. Then the message

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

will be called automatically.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! stackOverFlow is really a great site!

Comment: I accepted your answer. It solves the problem almost fine. There's a small problem that the final contentOffset is not the same as the table view auto-adjustment of contentOffset. The outcome is not perfect but good enough. Thanks.